# Trying to write a SQL query that lists values alphabetically by one column, and groups instances where 2 column values match

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

**Situation:**

BigQuery datatable id=vox-007.ds_007_01.dt_007_01oB

That datatable has columns named 'category' and 'es_representative_name'

I'm trying to run a Google SQL query that will list all the 'es_representative_name' values alphabetically, and also show the 'category'. I'd like to group all instances when the 'es_representative_name' and 'category' values are the same, and show the number of instances/rows.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT
  es_representative_name,
  category
FROM
  `vox-007.ds_007_01.dt_007_01oB`
ORDER BY
  es_representative_name ASC;
```

**Problem**

It restarts the alphabetical listing of the 'es_representative_name' value every time a new 'category' occurs. It also doesn't group instances where the 'es_representative_name' and 'category' values are the same in different rows.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT
  es_representative_name,
  ARRAY_AGG(category) AS categories
FROM
  `vox-007.ds_007_01.dt_007_01oB`
GROUP BY
  es_representative_name
ORDER BY
  es_representative_name ASC;
```

**Problem**

It wouldn't work because there are 'null' values for 'category'.

So I tried this query:

```
SELECT
  es_representative_name,
  ARRAY_AGG(category IGNORE NULLS) AS categories
FROM
  `vox-007.ds_007_01.dt_007_01oB`
GROUP BY
  es_representative_name
ORDER BY
  es_representative_name ASC;
```

**Problem**

It again restarted the alphabetical list of 'es_representative_name' values every time there was a new 'category' value. It also failed to group rows and count the records for instances when the 'es_representative_name' and 'category' values are the same for multiple rows.

I then tried this query:

```
SELECT
  es_representative_name,
  category,
  COUNT(*) AS row_count
FROM
  `vox-007.ds_007_01.dt_007_01oB`
GROUP BY
  es_representative_name,
  category
ORDER BY
  es_representative_name ASC,
  category ASC;
```

**Problem**

That's ones the closest, as it's grouping by 'category' correctly, but it's still restarting the alphabetical listing of the 'es_representative_name' values with each new category.

I then tried removing the ORDER BY command for 'category ASC':

```
SELECT
  es_representative_name,
  category,
  COUNT(*) AS row_count
FROM
  `vox-007.ds_007_01.dt_007_01oB`
GROUP BY
  es_representative_name,
  category
ORDER BY
  es_representative_name ASC;
```

**Problem**

That still restarted the alphabetical ordering for 'es_representative_name' values with each new category.

Is there something I'm missing about how to alphabetically list a datatable by column values? Any input on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with enough sample data to illustrate the possibly use cases and the result you want to achieve, based on that sample data. Provide the data as editable text

Comment: You are not being clear about the problem/ desired result.  For example, in the second to last example, you say, *it's still restarting the alphabetical listing of the 'es_representative_name' values with each new category* but the Order By you specified absolutely does not do what you described.

Comment: Thanks, @NickW and Chris Maurer . I set up a demo datatable and tried the first query in my list and it worked fine. Now I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't produce the same result on my datatable. It's 500+ rows, so too big to post here. But I'm thinking it has to be something about the GROUP command, so looking into that. I'll post any updates I find.

Comment: There is no way that first query *"restarts the alphabetical listing of the 'es_representative_name' value every time a new 'category' occurs"* given that `order by` clause. It simply isn't possible. Same with the last query. Is there more SQL you aren't sharing? Is this sql just part of a subquery? At this point there is no way to diagnose as your SQL isn't problematic and should produce what you want.